# How to test Input element with datalist in enzyme/jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I was initially using a Select element, doing a find and testing the children to see if the options contained expected values. But since then, I have switched to using an Input element with a datalist, to allow free form text entry as well as option selection, however I can't see how to test the same thing.

What I want to test is that the input element has rendered and the datalist contains the expected values.

My React code

```
<input type="text" list="categories" ref={this.categoryInput} className="Modal-Comment" name="CategoryInput" value={this.state.enteredCategory} onChange={ (e) => this.handleCategoryChanged(e)}/>
    <datalist id="categories">
        {this.groupOptions.map(o => this.MakeOption(o, this.state.enteredCategory))}
    </datalist>
```

and my Enyzme test code that previously tested the select element

```
  const categorySelect = wrapper.find('select').find('[name="CategoryInput"]');
  expect(categorySelect.exists()).toEqual(true);
  expect(categorySelect.children().filterWhere(x => x.text() === 'Expected option 1').length).toEqual(1);
  expect(categorySelect.children().filterWhere(x => x.text() === 'Expected option 2').length).toEqual(1);
```

I understand that I should change the find() to look for an input type, which is fine, but then I don't know how to look for the generated options in the datalist. The above test code returns 0 matching elements, I assume because the datalist is not a child of the input. In which case how should I test this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the datalist element is not a direct child element of the input element, you should create a separate selector for the datalist element:

```
const datalist = wrapper.find('#categories');

expect(datalist.children().length).toEqual(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should test the method(MakeOption method for example) directly - maybe in this case or in other cases that is not possible to test the results through props or state, it can be better.

the code should look something like this:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<NameOfComponent />);
expect(wrapper.instance().methodName()).toEqual(someValue);
```